# Why do Docs, Sheets and Slides keep recreating their data?

Tags: internal-storage, background-data

Look, I am *never, ever ever* going to use Docs, Sheets and Slides on my LG K7 (running 5.1.1), but I have come to terms with the fact that there is no way to remove them from my phone without rooting, which I am not interested in doing.  But I figure at least I can free up scarce storage space by erasing the apps' data, which typically is on the order of about 70 MB each.  Liberating 200+ MB of available space on a phone that only has 4GB internal storage, 3/4 of which is taken up with the OS and apps that can't be removed:  it means the difference between "Not enough space to update apps" / "Voicemails will not be downloaded" and normal operation.

But every time I clear this memory -- without fail -- I find that within 24 hours the data is recreated and I am right back where I started.  Note that I'm not *using* Docs, Sheets or Slides during this 24 hour period, so the apps are not running.  Why does this data keep getting recreated, and is there anything I can do to stop it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shoud **disable** those apps:

- Go to *Settings › Apps* – where you usually deleted the data
- before deleting data:

  - push the "force close" button to make sure the app is not running. Else it might recreate data before you reach the point of disabling it.
  - then push the "disable" button, so it won't start anymore.
  - on "disable" you might be asked if you wish to revert to the "factory version". Say yes: this will remove all updates the app has received, and which are stored in "user space" as well. So this will even free additional space
- finally push "clear cache" and "delete data", to complete the cleanup job.

Now that it's disabled, it won't start on its own anymore – and thus not collect or recreate any data. Nor should any updater pull updates for it.